# Property of closure relation.

Tags: combinatorics, matroids

I am reading $\textit{On the Foundations of Combinatorial Theory II. Combinatorial Geometries}$. They give a definition.

> A closure relation on a set $S$ is a function $A\mapsto \bar{A}$ defined for all subsets > $A\subseteq S$, satisfying
> $$
>     \overline{A}\subseteq S,\quad A\subseteq \overline{A},\quad
>     A\subseteq \overline{B}\text{ implies }\overline{A}\subseteq \overline{B}
> $$

They then write that we can prove that $\overline{A\cap B}=\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$. I can show that $\overline{A\cap B}\subseteq \overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$, but I cannot figure out the reverse containment. Is this even true in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there are some background assumptions that you’ve not stated, the assertion is false. Let $S=\Bbb R$, and for $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ let $\overline{A}$ be the usual topological closure of $A$ in $\Bbb R$. Then $A\subseteq\overline{A}\subseteq\Bbb R$ for all $A\subseteq\Bbb R$, and $A\subseteq\overline{B}$ implies that $\overline{A}\subseteq\overline{B}$, but if we set $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(1,2)$, then

$$\overline{A\cap B}=\overline{(0,1)\cap(1,2)}=\overline{\varnothing}=\varnothing\subsetneqq\{1\}=[0,1]\cap[1,2]=\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}\;.$$

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I guess the authors messed up? I was wondering if you could take a quick look (it's just one paragraph) and try to see what they mean. Image: https://imgur.com/a/JHO6kKo.

Comment: @Vasting: My best guess is that there’s a typo, and that it should be $\overline{A\cup B}=\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$.

Comment: I'll go with that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Vasting: You’re welcome!